# If condition that loops through an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, if-statement

I have an array which has several keys, each may be true/false:

```
$hide[1] = false; 
$hide[2] = false; 
$hide[3] = true;
```

I want a `<div>` block to appear in my HTML if at least one key is set to `true`:

```
<?php if ($some_condition_here==true) { ?> 
<div>show me if at least one value is "true"</div>
<?php } else { } ?>
```

What is the best practice to do this, considering that sometimes I don't know in advance how many keys I may have (in this example, 3, though might be more). I can assume that max number will be about 20 though.

I'm not sure how to do this, since I don't know how to use `loop` with `if`, and also it needs to stop checking on the first event it finds a `true`.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the function `in_array`, which checks if a certain value is in an array.

```
if( in_array( TRUE, $hide ) )
{
     echo '<div>show me if at least one value is "true"</div>';
}
```

It also seems like you don't know how functions work. You might want to read about them: http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php.

Even without `in_array` it would've been possible to implement it yourself by using a custom made function. That's essentially how you can use a loop with an if. Not recommended in this case, since we already know there's a function which does exactly what you need. I just included the example below for your education, NOT to be used. Use `in_array` like in my first example!

```
function my_custom_in_array( $needle, $stack )
{
    foreach( $stack as $v )
    {
        if( $v === $needle )
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

if( my_custom_in_array( TRUE, $hide ) )
{
     echo '<div>show me if at least one value is "true"</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for `true` value in array:

```
if (in_array(true, $hide)) {  /* do something */  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(in_array(true,$hide)){

echo '<div>show me if at least one value is "true"</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **in_array()**-function for this!

It checks if the first argument (true) is an your array ($hide).
And it stops immediately when the first **true** is found.

Just put it in an if()-Statement and enjoy!

```
if( in_array(true, $hide) )
{
   echo '<div> show me if at least one value is "true" </div>';
}
```

The code in the braces will only be executed if your array has at least one **true** in it!